# In the ubuntu desktop os all hard drive installation process; manually partitioning process to create in a gpt disk an efi partition; which contains s

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, uefi, disk, gpt

In the ubuntu desktop os all hard drive installation process; manually partitioning process to create in a gpt disk an efi partition; which contains some boot files; the partition is primary or logic?

Comment: Are you asking how to manually partition the storage device? If so, could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re installing (1) a lost showing existing partitions (that you would like to keep) (2) any other information that might be useful. If the computer will *only* have Ubuntu installed, than the manual partition process is generally unnecessary unless you’re trying to accomplish something very specific. The defaults are pretty decent for 99% of installations 

Answer (score 2):

"Primary" vs "Logical" partitions occur only on older MBR disk partitioning records. The "Logical" partitions are a workaround to MBR's limitation of four Primary (real) partitions.

Not GPT. There is no analogous "Logical" partition in GPT.

If somebody using GPT talks about a "Logical" partition, they are likely talking about using [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)), which is a completely different topic unrelated to MBR Logical partitions.